# Can not connect to Watson IoT - connection refused

Tags: watson-iot

I'm following [these instructions](https://developer.ibm.com/tv/mqtt-client-library-watson-iot-platform/) using the orgID given by the Watson IoT platform.

I then created the MQ Client in Node-RED using this orgID and 
d:orgID:mydevicetype:mydevicedid using arbitrary mydevicetype and mydevicedid.

These are the Node-RED error messages:

```
"Error: Connection refused: Not authorized"
"Error stopping node: Error: [BaseClient:disconnect] Client is not connected"
```

I then created a device on the Watson IoT platform using the mydevicetype and mydevicedid and eas provided a token. 
I got the same error using **use-token-auth** as the user and the token as password.

Device log on the Watson IoT platform:

```
Invalid userID () for device auth: 
ClientID='d:orgID:mydevicetype:mydevicdeid', 
ClientIP=169.50.40.xxx
```

Comment: can you share the node configuration from nodered? please mask your credentials. It might be some wrong in the configuration of the node

Comment: Hello, how can I retrieve events from Watson IoT using a REST API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try:

- url: `mqtts://[orgId].messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com`
- port:8883
- username: `use-token-auth`
- password: `[the token you got when you created the device]`
- client id: `d:[orgID]:[mydevicetype]:[mydeviceid]`

Looks like not much different from what you've tried, perhaps your are not using a secure (mqtts) connection ?

Comment: I added "mqtts://" to the URL and replaced the default port (1883). It's working now. Thx

Comment: Hi, if I have to use the HTTP APIs, what should be the username and password? I keep getting 403. :(

Answer (score 0):

If the client id that you are specifying really is:

```
d:orgID:mydevicetype:mydevicdeid
```

then your problem is that you need to specify the actual 6 character orgId, e.g.:

```
d:abcdef:mydevicetype:mydevicdeid
```

Give that a go and let us know how you get on.